# xsl: check if both strings are equal, if true then display another string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, tei

I have a first `TEI` which content is used for `XSLT` that you can find here http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y4/7

A second `TEI` in `corpus_ilimilku.xml` which I need to use in the same `XSLT` file:

```
<category n="1"  xml:id="contend" ana="#verb.competition">
     <catDesc xml:lang="en">subcategory of competition verb: contend 
         <lang> 
             <ref n="1" target="http://babelnet.org">BabelNet<idno type="URI">http://live.babelnet.org/synset?word=bn:00083498v</idno></ref>
             <ref n="2" target="https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/">FrameNet<idno type="URI">https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Attaching"></idno></ref>
         </lang>
      </catDesc> 
      <category ana="#transcription" xml:lang="uga">
          <gloss n="1" xml:id="ḫṣb01" target="../uga/verb.xsl#ḫṣb"/>
          <gloss n="2" xml:id="mḫṣ01" cert="high" target="../uga/verb.xsl#mḫṣ"/> 
      </category>
</category>
```

I don't have a problem to refer to the right file. I have checked, and it's working.

In fact, I have two problems:

1. `key` of `ref` that is not working I think,
2. so when I want to display `href5` of `$value-doc2` if `"$value-doc = translate($re-ana2, '#', '')` is true, I have the following message:

> Description: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of tokenize() (", "http://live.babelnet.org/synse...", "https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu...")

Currently, `"$value-doc = translate($re-ana2, '#', '')` works since I have tested with several values, and the result is `true` or `false`.  See last word of each `<li>`[image: print screen for <code>$check-id</code>]

What I would like to display:

```
<h3>mḫṣ</h3><em>
mean.: </em>to figth, to destroy. Inflected forms attested:
<ul>
 <li>tmtḫṣ: gram. → Gt. ind. imperf. trans, 2msg, 3fsg. <em>trans. </em>she fought -- remark(s): iterative function // with “<a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#ktu1-3_ii_l6b_t%E1%B8%ABt%E1%B9%A3b">tḫtṣb</a>.” Occur.: <a href="">ktu1.3:ii:l5b-6a</a> -- <em>analysis: </em>suggestion of 
  <a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#ktu1-3_ii_l5b_6a_int">hermeneutics;</a> taxo., subcat. of competition v. “<a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#m%E1%B8%AB%E1%B9%A301">contend</a>.” 
   <!-- DATA THAT I CANNOT DISPLAY : --> <a href="http://live.babelnet.org/synset?word=bn:00083498v">BabelNet</a>, <a href="https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Attaching">Framework</a>
  </li>
  <li>tmḫṣ: gram. → D. ind. perf. trans, 2msg, 3fsg. <em>trans. </em>she destroyed -- remark(s): 
  Occur.: <a href="">ktu1.3:ii:l7</a> -- <em>analysis: </em>suggestion of <a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#ktu1-3_ii_l7_int">hermeneutics;</a> taxo., subcat. of emotion's v. as a concept of “<a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#m%E1%B8%AB%E1%B9%A302">humiliation</a>.” 
   <!-- DATA THAT I CANNOT DISPLAY : --> <a href="http://live.babelnet.org/synset?word=bn:00083498v">BabelNet</a>, <a href="https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Attaching">Framework</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

To sum up: if `@xml:id` of `<gloss>` of second `TEI` (`corpus_ilimilku.xml`) = `@ana[2]` of `<re>` of current `TEI` (in Fiddle content), then display `idno @type URI` of each `ref` that belongs to same parent node of `gloss`.

I hope my explanation is clear. Sorry for my lack of English...

In advance, thank you.

Comment: Right answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the kind support of @Martin. First, I changed second `TEI`:

```
  <category n="1" xml:id="humiliation" ana="#verb.emotion">
     <catDesc >subcategory of emotion's verb as a concept of: humiliation
       <term ana="#mḫṣ02 #ṣmt01" type="baseForm">
          <ptr n="1" target="http://babelnet.org/synset?word=bn:00086117v" source="BabelNet" />
          <ptr n="2" target="" source="WordNet" next="{01804206}" />
          <ptr n="3" target="http://verbs.colorado.edu/propbank/framesets-english-aliases/humiliate.html" source="VerbNet" />
          <ptr n="4" target="http://verbs.colorado.edu/html_groupings/wound-n.html" source="VerbNet" />
          <ptr n="5" target="https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Stimulate_emotion" source="FrameNet" />
        </term>
      </catDesc>
      <category ana="#verb.emotion #humiliation" xml:lang="uga">
          <gloss n="1" xml:id="mḫṣ02" cert="high"/> 
      </category>  
    </category>
```

Then for `XSL`, following addition:

```
<xsl:param name="f2" select="'../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml'"/>

<!-- key to look for @xml:id of <gloss> within TEI -->
<xsl:key name="gloss-ref" match="category[category/gloss]" use="category/gloss/@xml:id"/>
<!-- variable for "f2" -->
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($f2)"/>

<!-- within template match="entryFree" and <ul><li> -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('gloss-ref', translate($re-ana2, '#', ''), $doc2)//term/ptr[@target]"/>

<!-- template to display <xsl:apply-templates> -->
<xsl:template match="ptr">
    <xsl:variable name="href-ptr-target" select="@target"/>
    <a href="{$href-ptr-target}">
     <xsl:value-of select="@source"/>
     <xsl:if test="@next">
      <xsl:value-of select="@next"/>
     </xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>. </xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Result, according to Fiddle http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y4/9, new `XSL` (between `<!-- -->` in Fiddle), and second `TEI` content:

```
<ul>
  <li>tmḫṣ: gram. → D. ind. perf. trans, 2msg, 3fsg. <em>trans. </em>she destroyed -- remark(s): Occur.: <a href="">ktu1.3:ii:l7</a> -- <em>analysis: </em>suggestion of <a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#ktu1-3_ii_l7_int">hermeneutics;</a> taxo., subcat. of emotion's v. as a concept of “<a href="../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml#m%E1%B8%AB%E1%B9%A302">humiliation</a>.” Related to: <a href="http://babelnet.org/synset?word=bn:00086117v">BabelNet, </a><a href="">WordNet{01804206}, </a><a href="http://verbs.colorado.edu/propbank/framesets-english-aliases/humiliate.html">VerbNet, </a><a href="http://verbs.colorado.edu/html_groupings/wound-n.html">VerbNet, </a><a href="https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Stimulate_emotion">FrameNet.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the line

```
<!-- DATA THAT I CANNOT DISPLAY : --> <a href="http://live.babelnet.org/synset?word=bn:00083498v">BabelNet</a>, <a href="https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Attaching">Framework</a>
```

is meant to explain that you want to transform the

```
document('../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml')//lang/ref/idno
```

elements into links then where you want to create those links use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml')//lang/ref/idno"/>
```

and then write a template

```
<xsl:template match="idno">
  <a href="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::node()[1]"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

that produces those links (I am not quite sure about the link content, for the first `BabelNet` seems as described, for the second the is `FrameNet` versus `Framework`).

As for using keys with several documents, keys work on a per document basis and the `key` function has an optional third argument you can specify to search e.g `$doc2` with values from the context document with e.g. `key('key-name', (key-value-or-values), $doc2)`.

I think your verbal description

> if @xml:id of  of second TEI (corpus_ilimilku.xml) = @ana[2] of
>    of current TEI (in Fiddle content), then display idno @type URI
>   of each ref that belongs to same parent node of gloss

translates into a key declaration

```
<xsl:key name="gloss-ref" match="category[category/gloss]" use="category/gloss/@xml:id"/>
```

then let's assume we have a global variable `<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="doc('../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml')"/>` I think you want to use the key function with e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('gloss-ref', $re-ana2, $doc2)//lang/ref/idno"/>
```

to process the relevant `idno` elements.

Comment: Thank you @Martin! I think I understand `apply-templates` now. Regarding `key`, I did now: `<xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$check-id = true()"> <xsl:if test="key('ref', @n and @type, document('../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml'))"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="$idno-ref"/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise/> </xsl:choose>` (where `$idno-ref` is for `document('../computation/corpus_ilimilku.xml')//lang/ref/idno`), but I have all `idno` of the document for each string `$check-id = true()` . What do I get wrong?

Comment: I have tried also `xsl:for-each` instead of `xsl:if` following the last answer of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620527/how-do-i-apply-templates-to-each-selected-node-in-a-for-each), but again it doesn't work.

Comment: Why does `key('ref', @n and @type ...)` use a boolean expression `@n and @type` for the key value?

Comment: Right. So I change by `<xsl:if test="$check-id">`. I want to display content only if `$check-id`. But I still have all `idno` and several times in each `string`.

Comment: I found the solution. Just updated with the new answer. Thanks again @Martin.